# Recommended Setup for BigData Application

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, cassandra, hive, apache-pig

I am currently working on a long term project that will need to support:

- Lots of fast Read/Write operations via RESTful Services
- An Analytics Engine continually reading and making sense of data

**It is vital that the performance of the Analytics Engine not be affected by the volume of Reads/Writes coming from the API calls.**

Because of that, I'm thinking that I may have to use a "front-end" database and some sort of "back-end" data warehouse. I would also need to have something like Elastic Search or Solr indexing the data stored in the data warehouse.

**The Questions:**

1. Is this a Recommended Setup? What would the alternative be?

**If so...**

2. I'm considering either Hive or Pig for the data-warehousing, and Elastic Search or Solr as a Search Engine. Which combination is known to work better together?

**And finally...**

3. I'm seriously considering Cassandra as the "fron-end" database. What is the relation between Cassandra and Hadoop, and when/why should they be put to work together instead of having just Cassandra?

Please note, **my intention is NOT to start a debate about which of these is better, but to understand how can they be put to work better more efficiently.** If it makes any difference, the main code is being written in Scala and Java.

I truly appreciate your help. I'm basically learning as I go and all comments will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's talk about Cassandra

This is a NoSQL database with eventual consistency which basically means for you that different nodes into a Cassandra cluster may have different 'snapshots' of data in the case that there is an inter cluster communication/availability problem. The data eventually will be consistent however.

Since you consider it as a 'frontend' database what you need to understand is how you will model your data. Cassandra can take advantage of indexes however you still need to defined upfront your access pattern.

Normally there is no relation between Cassandra and Hadoop (except that both are written in Java) however the Datastax distribution (enterprise version) has Hadoop support directly from Cassandra.

As a general workflow you will read/write most current data (let's say - last 24 hours) from your 'small' database that enough performance (Cassandra has excellent support for it) and you would move anything older than X (older than 24 hours) to a 'long term storage' such as Hadoop where you can run all sort of Map Reduce etc.

In regards to the text search it really depends what you need - Elastic Search is sort of competition to Solr and reverse. You can see yourself how they compare here http://solr-vs-elasticsearch.com/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me see if I got this straight: Hadoop works as a good Data Warehouse solution without Hive or Pig? What is their added benefit, then?

Comment: Hive, Pig are 'higher level' tools on top of Hadoop - yes Hadoop will work w/o -> ps: click if you accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

As for your third question,

I think Cassandra is more like a database to save data.

Hadoop is responsible to provide a compution model to let you analyze your large data in 
Cassandra.
So it is very helpful to combine Cassandra with Hadoop.

Also have other ways you can consider, such as combine with mongo and hadoop, 
for mongo has support mongo-connector between hadoop and it's data.

Also if you have some search requirements , you can also use solr,  directly generated index from mongo.